# File I/O not reading in anything

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm having a problem reading in and writing out the contents of the text file.
I'm trying to read in questions, answers, and wrong answers separately but I'm not getting anything to read.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Question.h"
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Question::Question()
{
    this->m_question = "";
    this->m_question = "";
    this->m_wrongAns1 = "";
    this->m_wrongAns2 = "";
    this->m_wrongAns3 = "";
    char trash[256];
    char value[256];
    int count;
}
Question::Question(string p_question, string p_answer, string p_wrongAns1, string p_wrongAns2, string p_wrongAns3)
{
    this->m_question = p_question;
    this->m_question = p_answer;
    this->m_wrongAns1 = p_wrongAns1;
    this->m_wrongAns2 = p_wrongAns2;
    this->m_wrongAns3 = p_wrongAns3;
    char trash[256];
    char value[256];
    int count;
}
string Question::getQuestion(string p_filename)
{
    ifstream myfile(p_filename);
    char trash[256];
    char value[256];
    myfile.getline(trash, 256);     //Linebreak
    myfile.getline(trash, 256);     //Name tag
    myfile.getline(value, 256);     //Name
    m_question.assign(value);
    cout << m_question;
    return m_question;
}
string Question::getAnswer(string p_filename)
{
    return "";
}
vector<string> Question::getWrongAnswers(string p_filename)
{
    vector<string> questionList;
    vector <string> ::iterator questionIt;
    return questionList;
}
```

This is supposed to read in by the line and assign the value to a variable and the trash is just left.

Questions\Questions.txt

```
Which of the following is NOT a type of virtual collaboration:
Skype
igoogle documents
Hand-written letter Answer
Email

Which of the following are types of CMC?
Video
Instant Messengers Answer
Phone
BlueJ
```

In main I just do a simple call of:

```
 getQuestions("Questions\\Questions.txt";
```

Comment: A good start would be to see which of your operations fail. Based on the code, I would guess, it fails to open the file but you can check if it does: `if (!myfile) { std::cout << "failed to open file '" << p_filename << "'\n"; }` Likewise, you should check that you could input something, e.g., (`if (!myfile.getline(trash, 256)) { ...}`).

Comment: Strange code, why do you have `char trash[256]; char value[256]; int count;` at the end of both your constructors?

Comment: Aw i dont nknow what i was thinking with that i was supposed to take it out lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code

```
ifstream myfile(p_filename);
```

to this

```
ifstream myfile(p_filename);
if (!myfile.is_open())
    cerr << "could not open file\n";
```

and see what happens.

Almost certainly the reason your code fails is that you fail to open the file, so test that theory first.

Comment: Ye it fails to open the file what could that mean?

Comment: There are many reason that a file might fail to open, but the most likely is that your program is looking for it in a different place to where is really is. You say it is here `"Questions\\Questions.txt"`,  where do you think that means? And what gives you confidence that your program understands what you mean?

Comment: `"Questions\\Questions.txt"` is what's called a *relative path*, but what is it relative to? Do you know, or think you know? You might be better using an *absolute path*.

Comment: The reason this is difficult is that how a C++ program finds a file has nothing at all to do with the C++ language. It has to do with your operating system (whatever that is) and how you run your program (however that is). So it's hard to give specific advice unless you give more detail.

Comment: Got it sorted u wer correct i moved it beside the .exe and it worked :)